# Trying to figure out what these elements have in common

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal, periodic-table, elements, metallurgy

I have an old periodic table and I marked five metals from groups 1A and 2A with dots to indicate something about them. Only all this time later I can't figure out what exactly it was. I've been trying to figure it out for ages.

The elements are: Li, Na, K, Ca, Ba.

Doesn't anyone know any properties that just those elements, or maybe even just primarily those five, share that I could have been marking them for?

Comment: Their salts burn nice and colourful... red, yellow, purple, red, green (but there are many more that do that). See at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_test)

Comment: Maybe your assumption was *the exam questions are about these five*? Or it could be *these elements' cations are commonly seen in ionic compounds*? There are countless possibilities, that would render answering (better put it as guessing) this almost impossible.

Answer (score 1):

They are all member of the s block in the periodic table. It means they all have valence electron in the s orbital.

Comment: other elements are also s-block and are not marked so I suspect that this is not the reason